# mov DS,[BX] and mov DS,[1234]

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Hi I'm starting assembly language and sorry for my basic question.

are these two instructions valid in assembly language?
(8086 mov instruction).

1. mov DS,[BX]
2. mov DS,[1234]

if no,why not?!

Comment: Which assembler (piece of software) are you using?  Those may be valid in one, but not another.  There are differences in how the syntax is expressed regarding loads in some of them.

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid, examples for `8E /r MOV Sreg,r/m16 Move r/m16 to segment register`.

```
8E 1F       mov DS,[BX]
8E 1E D2 04 mov DS,[1234]
```

Next time please consult an instruction set reference.

Comment: sorry , havn't starting work with computer yet, just researching and learning about the assembly language.
i'm going to use masm 32.
but my question was generally about moving address and with pointer to Data segment register is allowed or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov DS,[BX]
```

puts the content pointed by BX to DS(Data segment)

```
mov DS,[1234]
```

puts the content in address 1234 into DS

both instructions are valid.